# What is the difference between a perturbative and a non-perturbative vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, vacuum, perturbation-theory, non-perturbative

What is the difference between a perturbative and a non-perturbative vacuum in quantum field theory? Is there an analog of these ideas in non-relativistic quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an interacting (not necessarily relativistic) quantum field theory, whose Hamiltonian can be written as $H = H_{\rm free} + \lambda H_{\rm int}$, where the second term is a small interaction Hamiltonian with strength $\lambda$ and the first term is the free Hamiltonian. Then, generically we have two vacuum states $|\Omega\rangle \neq |0\rangle$, where $H|\Omega\rangle=E_{\Omega}$ and $H_{\rm free} |0\rangle=0$. In other words, $|0\rangle$ is no longer the "lowest energy state" since the introduction of an interaction shifts the energy spectrum. The non-perturbative vacuum (or the actual lowest energy state) is $|\Omega\rangle$.

Comment: Do you mean that the non-perturbative vacuum is simply the vacuum of the full interacting theory?